# Is there anyway to open jquery dialog behind the current page or minimize it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

Is there anyway to open jquery dialog behind the current page or minimize it?

I tried window.focus() but didn't help.

Comment: Are you trying to create a popup?

Comment: What would be the point of opening it "behind the current page"?

Comment: @j08691 presenting ads

Comment: who can read ads when they are behind the page?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about a jQuery dialog as far as the browser is concerned - it's just HTML with styling and some JavaScript running the show. As such, there is no "special" way to present one in a separate window.

To do what you want, you'll need to create a popup the normal way (e.g. `window.open`) that points to a page which produces a jQuery dialog.

However, you're not going to get a standalone jQuery Dialog floating in space - it'll be a browser window with the usual toolbars, status bars, close button, etc.

Comment: "you're not going to get a standalone jQuery Dialog floating in space" this is wrong. I have seen Chuck Norris doing exactly that! :)

Comment: @naveen: It has been said that if you try to close one of Chuck Norris' popups, Chuck Norris will pop you in the mouth with a roundhouse.